# Cookie set in other servlet is not set in the request to a different servlet of the same application

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, cookies, servlet-filters

i have an ear application deployed to on a JBOSS 8 server. The frontend part is a JSF application. In the frontend.war I have defined two servlets:

1. JSF 2.2 servlet for my GUI, runs locally on 127.0.0.1:8080/app
2. MockAuthenticationServlet, runs locally on 127.0.0.1:8080/app/auth

The MockAuthenticationServlet just sets a cookie (test cookie) like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(COOKIE_NAME, "12345");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    resp.addCookie(cookie);
    resp.sendRedirect("/app");
}
```

Here is the method from the ServletFilter which is called from doFiter:

```
private Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getCookies() != null) {
        for (Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
            if (c.getName().equals(COOKIE_NAME)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
    }

    return (Cookie) request.getAttribute(COOKIE_NAME);
}
```

The last return was just for a case where it is sent as an attribute. The cookie is supposed to be returned from the loop.

I have debugged the MockAuthenticationServlet and the Cookie gets set, I also see it when I open browser cookies list. However, in my ServletFilter, where I want to check if this cookie is set the list of cookies in the request is null. Am I missing something? Thanks for your tips.

Comment: post the servlet filter's code and are you checking after the cookie is set or before it

Comment: I have added the filter method which obtains the cookie. The filter checks every request that goes to /javax.faces.resource. The plan is to redirect to the MockAuthenticationServlet if the cookie is not set. Once it is set from the MockAuthenticationServlet it should be redirected back. Again I have to say I see the cookie in the browser, but in the java code when I debug it is empty. The domain is the same 127.0.0.1, just the context path is changed.

Comment: Use a browser plugin to determine if the cookie is actually being sent to the server or not. If it is, provide the full set of HTTP headers in your question.